# Functions satisfying $f(x)+f(\frac{1}{1-x})=x$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\}.$

Tags: functional-equations

I have used this identity: if $g(x)=1/(1-x),$ then
$$g^{-1}(x)=1-\frac{1}{x},$$ 
to get all functions satisfying: $f(x)+f(\frac{1}{1-x})=x$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\},$ but I didn't get a general form of its solution. My question here is:

> Is there any simple method to solve the titled functional equation?

Comment: What is your equation?

Comment: What do you mean by a function satisfying an expression? Functions, or any type of objects can satisfy formulas, not expressions. E.g., it makes sense to ask what functions satisfy $f(x)+f(1/x)=x^2$. This is a formula.

Comment: Thanks , i have fixed it

Comment: Could you please tell me how $\left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right)^{-1}=1-\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: The exponent $-1$ stands for the reverse. If you substitute $1/(1-x)$ and $1-1/x$ in the functional equation and solve three simultaneous equations may we can get the general solution form

Comment: Please check my edit, that it's what you want. I'm assuming you wanted $x$ to be a real number not equal to $0$ or $1$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes of course what you edited is true

Comment: I've also clarified the function inverse notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S:=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,1\}$.  Let $g:S\to S$ be defined by $$g(x):=\frac{1}{1-x}\text{ for all }x\in S\,.$$
Prove that $g\circ g\circ g$ is the identity function $\text{id}_S$ on $S$.

Thus, we have
$$f(x)+f\big(g(x)\big)=x\,,$$
$$f\big(g(x)\big)+f\big((g\circ g)(x)\big)=g(x)\,,$$
and
$$f\big((g\circ g)(x)\big)+f(x)=(g\circ g)(x)\,,$$
for all $x\in S$.

> This shows that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\,\Big(x+(g\circ g)(x)-g(x)\Big)\text{ for every }x\in S\,.$$  In other words, $$f(x)=\frac{x^3-x+1}{2x(x-1)}\text{ for all }x\in S\,.$$  In fact, if $h:S\to S$ is arbitrary, then the solution $f:S\to S$ to the functional equation $$f(x)+f\big(g(x)\big)=h(x)\text{ for all }x\in S$$ is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\,\Big(h(x)+(h\circ g\circ g)(x)-(h\circ g)(x)\Big)\text{ for each }x\in S\,.$$  (See, for example, [Determine all functions $f$ satisfying the functional relation $f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{2(1-2x)}{x(1-x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938359/determine-all-functions-f-satisfying-the-functional-relation-fxf-left-fra?rq=1).)

Comment: Notice that similar reasoning applies whenever $g^{2k+1} = \text{id}$ for any $k\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 0):

We will prove that $$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2(1-x)}$$ when
$$f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x$$
At first we get $$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ and we get

$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Now we get

$$f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$
so
$$f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$
and we obtain

using that
$$f\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=x-f(x)$$
$$x-f(x)+\frac{x-1}{x}-f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
so $$2f(x)=x+\frac{x-1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$$

and $$f(x)=\frac{-x^3+x-1}{x}$$

Comment: The equation after "Now weget" is wrong.  The right-hand side should be $1-\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Ok i will check it!

Comment: You should fix the lines after the correction, though.

Comment: Can you show it to me, i have lost it.

Comment: The line starting with $x-f(x)+x-f(x)$ is clearly a carried-over mistake.